# Load a variable php page with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

My goals is to load a div from any php page. I'm using the jQuery function .load for this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#crumb').load('example.php #hello');
    });
    </script>
```

I want example.php to be welcome.php or test.php or about.php. It depends on which page is loaded within the container of the index. Any ideas?

Comment: So `http://example.com/blahblah.php` would have to do a `.load('blahblah.php #hello')`?

Comment: Thx for your suggestion :)

However i do not entirely understand how to use this. My pages are load as follows: url: blabla.nl/index.php?P=PAGENAME

how do i fetch this loaded pagename and display one div of it?

Comment: so the `P` query parameter specifies which page to load?

Comment: Exactly.

See my php code here, maybe you can use it :)

       <!-- START Page Content -->
    <div="pages" valign="top"><?
            if(empty($_GET['p'])) $_GET['p'] = "welkom";
   if(file_exists($_GET['p'] . ".php") && !empty($_GET['p'])) include($_GET['p'] . ".php"); 
   else include("welkom.php");
   ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function $_GET(q, s) { 
    s = s ? s : window.location.search; 
    var re = new RegExp('&'+q+'(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)','i'); 
    return (s=s.replace(/^?/,'&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined; 
}

/*
 * Edited here
 */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#crumb').load(($_GET('p') !== undefined ? ('index.php?p=' + $_GET('p')) : 'welcom.php') + ' #hello');
});
```

Comment: Thx, but does not work for me. The div is not displayed at all

Comment: I think i'm doing this too difficult. Forgive me, i am not an experienced web designer.

Wat I want to do is display breadcrumbs above the pages container in this format: "Home > current page"

Is this possible with jquery or javascript or whatever?

Comment: @Forza, wait a minute, I am updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

To do so consider the following:

Javascript

```
function GetDiv(url,tdiv) {
$("#GetDivResult").load(url,function() {
HandleResult(tdiv);
});
}
function HandleResult(tdiv){
$("#crumb").html($(tdiv).html());
}
function StartNow(){
var url = prompt("Enter the URL");
var tdiv = prompt("What DIV you want to show? example: #hello");
GetDiv(url,tdiv);
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="StartNow()">Begin</a>
<div id="GetDivResult" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="crumb"></div>
```

This is a simple example so you get the idea behind it..